# Apache Commons HTTPClient 3.x leaving connections open

Tags: servlets, gwt-rpc, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using HttpClient to execute a PostMethod against a remote servlet and for some reason a lot of my connections are hanging open and hogging up all of my server's connections.
Here's more info about the architecture
GWT client calls into a GWT Service
GWT service instantiates a HttpClient, creates a PostMethod and has the client execute the method
it then gets the input stream by calling method.getResponseBodyAsStream() and writes it out to a byte array
it then closes the input stream and flushes the byte array output stream, does a few more lines of code and then calls method.releaseConnection()

There has to be something obvious I'm overlooking that's causing this.  If I perform a GET in a browser to the same service, the connections close immediately but something about HTTPClient is causing them to hang open.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call HttpMethodBase#releaseConnection(). If you return a InputStream to be used later, a simple way is to wrap it by a anonymous FilterInputStream overwriting close():

```
final HttpMethodBase method = ...;
return new FilterInputStream(method.getResponseBodyAsStream())
{
  public void close() throws IOException
  {
    try {
      super.close();
    } finally {
      method.releaseConnection();
    }
  }
};
```